# Antivirus for Windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, security, anti-virus, windows-server-2008-r2

Would someone, please, give me few recommendation for antivirus software on windows server 2008 R2?  Do I need one, as nothing will be installed on server, it is not used for storing files?
Are there some Microsoft solutions (like microsoft essentials for PCs)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) installs and works on Windows Server 2008R2.

Comment: MSE should be used for this type of operating system.  Microsoft of course does has a very similar program.  MSE is unlikely support on Windows Server for this reason

Comment: Yes there is a reason, its name is ForeFront Security which is obviously paid.